# How to Wait for method (which calls on other methods/procedures/functions) to complete before continuing

Tags: c#

Forgive my semantics and programming ignorance.
I'm wanting to run a method, then wait for it to complete before continuing.  The initial method makes calls to 2 others and I can't figure out how/where to put 'continue to the next step ONLY AFTER you've completely finished'.

When searching around I came across various ways for Synchronous and Asynchronous methods.

1. I've tried using `Task t = Task.Run(() => startDownload(BTurl, BTlocation))` along with `Task.WaitAll()` or `t.wait()` with no luck.
2. Attempted await but the methods aren't `async`.  (althought `startDownloading()` has a call to `AsyncCompletedEventHandler()` which leads to a lot of my confusion).
3. Tried `EventWaitHandle` with `_ready.Set` in various locations (see commented locations A, B and C with findings).
4. Next was adding `private readonly ManualResetEvent _resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);` under class and `_resetEvent.Set()` and `resetEvent.WaitOne()` similar to `EventWaitHandle`.
5. I kind of tried `thread.Join()` in `startDownload()`.  No joy.
6. Tried `Process.Start.......WaitForExit()` with `startDownload()`.   Nope

I know I'm getting somewhere and yet nowhere.  For some reason I may need to convert(?) `startDownload()` to an `async` method.  This is where my confusion lies because my search results demonstrated how to 'wait'
from within a single method and the method I'm using makes calls to 2 others.

In the end though, for me this is a for-fun and learning project.  Though I may have jump in a little too deep. [blush]

```
namespace Download_Extract
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //static EventWaitHandle _ready = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        //static EventWaitHandle _go = new AutoResetEvent(false);


        // ***Download and extract***
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string BTurl = "https://the/file/is/located/here/self_extracting_7z_file.exe";
            string BTlocation = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "self_extracting_7z_file.exe");

            startDownload(BTurl, BTlocation);
            //_ready.WaitOne();             //wait here until _ready.Set() is retruned

            label3.Text = "Extracting Files.......";    //_ready.Set() has been received
            Process.Start(BTlocation, @"-aoa -y -oc:\dest_folder").WaitForExit();
            label3.Text = "Extracting Files Completed";
        }

        private void startDownload(string BTurl, string BTlocation)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(BTurl), BTlocation);
            });
            thread.Start();
            //_ready.Set();     // test C  *ProgressBar works, but doesn't wait for completed dl before continuing
        }

        void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
                double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
                double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
                label3.Visible = true;
                label3.Text = "Downloading.... "; // + e.BytesReceived + " of " + e.TotalBytesToReceive;
                label10.Visible = true;
                label10.Text = String.Format("{0:0}", percentage) + "%";
                progressBar1.Visible = true;
                progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
            });
            //_ready.Set();     // test B  *ProgressBar works, but doesn't wait for completed dl before continuing
        }

        void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                label10.Visible = false;
                label3.Text = "Download completed.";
            });
            //_ready.Set();     // test A  *works, but with issues. pBar delayed, no #%.text shown
        }
    }
}
```

Desired outcome of Button1_Click:
Download file.
    while downloading, show the Progress Bar and % complete...
Extract file after download is complete.

Error I'm getting:

> Message=The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

(trying to extract while still downloading)

Comment: Note that the `Async` in the `WebClient` method names doesn't have much to do with `async/await`. Its just saying that the method call won't block. Those classes are old, before `async/await` was introduced in .NET 4

Comment: I'm not sure why you are attracting downvotes, but I cleaned up the formatting so its less "wall of text"-y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic use case for `async` as you seem to be on the road towards.

```
_ready.WaitOne();             //wait here until _ready.Set() is returned
```

is your problem, because it blocks the calling thread, which in this case is the *UI* thread. Thus, the app freezes and no text/progress bars are updated. The classic solution is to use a `TaskCompletionSource`.

```
private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _downloadSource;
```

Your button click becomes:

```
private async void Button_Click(…)
{
    _downloadSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    // Start download
    await _downloadSource.Task
    // Extract
 }
```

The `async` keyword just allows you to use `await`. Note that `async void` is bad practice, except with event handlers (lots of good content out there about why).

Finally when the download is complete:

```
  _downloadSource.TrySetResult(true);
```

This does the same thing as an `AutoResetEvent` but asynchronously. What C# means by that is that the *method* invocation blocks, but the thread is allowed to run. The task system will return the method to the original invocation context when the task completes (at least, by default). [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await) has much more information on async/await and `Task`/`Task<T>`